# Is there any way in drupal to get all primary links through views?

Tags: views, 7, routes, services

My objective is to get the primary links or any kind of menus items, to be shown as JSON, so that an app could consume it and show it.

I tried it using views and I have services module and views_datasource as well, but no success.

If there is no easy way then I am open to build a custom module as well.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you create a hook_menu() and then in the callback do a https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_tree_all_data/7 to get the menu tree and then expose that to services or return  json.

Comment: I was thinking about it, but could you suggest me a good tutorials to expose my module to services, or how does integration with services module work?

Comment: you can create a custom services resource here https://www.drupal.org/node/783460 or the cheap way is to return json from your hook_menu()

Comment: Well..I would have returned json as a last resort, but I will play with this services stuff first. Thanks :)